# 'name' property when a type is both indexable and callable

Tags: typescript

I have a type like:

```typescript
interface MyInterface {
  (key?: string): MyReturnType;
  readonly [key: string]: MyReturnType;
}
```

So that `instance('foo')` and `instance.foo` are both possible.

I need to also be access the `name` property (ie `instance.name` is a `MyReturnType`), but this conflicts with the built-in [`Function`'s `name` property](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/bb306a757b17aef8b0881a1c252d720bfe7eeb1b/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L93-L98), so TypeScript recognises it as a `string`.

I've tried various options and can't find a way to get round it, without declaring an explicit `name` property in `MyInterface` (which is a pain, as I want *all* properties to be a `MyReturnType`). Is it possible? Is this a bug?

Refs https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/41082#discussion_r360391625.

Comment: Note I'm adding types for an existing NPM library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rdfjs/namespace) rather than writing the implementation.

Comment: Is this describing a `Proxy` or something?  If you have a value `myInterface` of type `MyInterface`, is `typeof myInterface` not `"function"` at runtime?  In any case I think the only way to do this is to manually specify any properties with types that conflict with the "default" ones from `Function` and `Object`.  I'm skeptical, though... you want `myInterface.apply` to be a `MyReturnType`?  Or `myInterface.toString`?  How about `myInterface.constructor`?

Comment: @jcalz Yep, it is a `Proxy`. To confirm, they all need to be overridden (https://runkit.com/thewilkybarkid/rdfjs-namespace-proxy/1.0.0).

Comment: I think TypeScript doesn't *want* to make this easy for you, then.  Proxies that break type expectations are not a use case for which the language is optimized.  For any reasonable value named `schema`,  the code `(schema || {}).toString()` should produce a `string`, but in the provided example we'd get a runtime error since `toString` is not a function.  It's not impossible to tell TypeScript otherwise, but for better or worse, it's tedious.